# Change values in json item which is list

Tags: python, json, caching

I need to change values of items "Id" "SummaryId" and "CoworkersId" in my json. I have already code which will change values of "Id" and `"SummaryId"`. Code below generates new unique Id for these 2 items. I need that this code will change "CoworkersId" as well. As you can see the same value is in these 3 items - a4555752s. The issue is that item "CoworkersId" is a list, not a string and contain 2 elements.

```
import json
import random

class Cache:
    # A dictionary that keeps a record of "seen" keys
    key_cache = {}

    @classmethod
    def generate_replacement_key(cls, key: str) -> str:
        """
            If key has already been seen, then return the cached key for that, 
            otherwise generate and store a new key.
        """
        new_key = cls.key_cache.setdefault(key, cls.generate_random_key())
        return new_key
    
    @classmethod
    def generate_random_key(cls) -> str:
        """
            returns a random key, that hasn't been generated before
        """
        new_key = str(random.randint(1000, 1000000))
        if new_key in cls.key_cache.values():
            return cls.generate_random_key()
        return new_key
        
a = '''
{
    "people": [
        {
            "Name": "Jan",
            "Lastname": "Szewc",
            "Id": "a4555752s"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Marek",
            "Lastname": "Piorun",
            "Id": "a4asa85",
            "SummaryId": "a4555752s"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Mikolaj",
            "Lastname": "Ciekasz",
            "Id": "a4ddd244",
            "ManagerId": "a4555752s",
            "CoworkersId":
            [   "1278978",
                "a4555752s"]
        }
]}
'''
data = json.loads(a)


for people in data["people"]:
    # use walrus operator to make less boilerplate-code.
    if (id_string := people.get("Id")): # use dict.get to avoid key-errors.
        people["Id"] = Cache.generate_replacement_key(id_string)
    if (summary_id_string := people.get("SummaryId")):
        people["SummaryId"] = Cache.generate_replacement_key(summary_id_string)
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

I need that values of all 3 elements `"Id"`, `"SummaryId"` and `"CoworkersId"` will be changed.

Comment: What is `SummaryId`? I don't see any item with `SummaryId` in your `data`.

Comment: Hi sorry you are right, now there is SummaryId

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all the coworker ids to modify them, like this:

```
for people in data["people"]:
    # use walrus operator to make less boilerplate-code.
    if (id_string := people.get("Id")): # use dict.get to avoid key-errors.
        people["Id"] = Cache.generate_replacement_key(id_string)
    if (summary_id_string := people.get("SummaryId")):
        people["SummaryId"] = Cache.generate_replacement_key(summary_id_string)
    
    # Here's the new code, looping through all coworker ids and changing them
    if (coworker_id_list := people.get("CoworkersId")):
        for i, coworker_id_string in enumerate(coworker_id_list):
            coworker_id_list[i] = Cache.generate_replacement_key(coworker_id_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, but there must be more efficient method, this is just a quick thing.
SummeryId and Id of the first object are the same because in json that you supplied they are the same, this means that:

```
key_cache = {}

@classmethod
    def generate_replacement_key(cls, key: str) -> str:
        new_key = cls.key_cache.setdefault(key, cls.generate_random_key())
        return new_key
```

will return the same value since it already exists in the dict.

```
data = (json.loads(a))['people']
alist = [] 
for people in data:
    newId = ''
    if (id_string := people.get("Id")): # use dict.get to avoid key-errors.
        newId = Cache.generate_replacement_key(id_string)
        people["Id"] = newId
        alist.append(newId)
        
    if (summary_id_string := people.get("SummaryId")):
        newId = Cache.generate_replacement_key(summary_id_string)
        people["SummaryId"] = newId
    
for obj in data:
    if "CoworkersId" in obj:     
        for idx, i in enumerate(alist):
            if i == obj.get('Id'):
                alist.pop(idx)
        obj["CoworkersId"] = alist
        
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

##### Output

```json
[
  {
    "Name": "Jan",
    "Lastname": "Szewc",
    "Id": "195229"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Marek",
    "Lastname": "Piorun",
    "Id": "202461",
    "SummaryId": "195229"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Mikolaj",
    "Lastname": "Ciekasz",
    "Id": "114871",
    "ManagerId": "a4555752s",
    "CoworkersId": [
      "195229",
      "202461"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This assumes `CoworkersId` contains a list of all other users' Ids, and in this case adds a third element to `CoworkersId`, rather than keeping the list length and modifying the ids.

Comment: Corrected. Is it what you meant?